# PHP XML to Array/Object with Attributes and Values

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xml-parsing

AI have an XML which have attributes as well as values in them. I want to convert it to an Array or Array Object along with attributes and values.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<itemBody>
<div label="options">
  <optionchoices optionIdentifier="RESPONSE" shuffle="false" maxOptions="1">
    <choice identifier="A1"><![CDATA[aaaa]]></choice>
    <choice identifier="A2"><![CDATA[bbbb]]></choice>
    <choice identifier="A3"><![CDATA[cccc]]></choice>
  </optionchoices>
</div>
</itemBody>
```

I tried two set of code but the result was not as expected.

**Code 1**

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml', 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
echo "<pre>";print_r($xml);echo "</pre>"; exit;
?>
```

**Output**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [div] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [label] => options
                )

            [optionchoices] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [optionIdentifier] => RESPONSE
                            [shuffle] => false
                            [maxOptions] => 1
                        )

                    [choice] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => aaaa
                            [1] => bbbb
                            [2] => cccc
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

In the above output if we check then in choice node we get the **values only** and not the attributes

**Code 2**

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
echo "<pre>";print_r($xml);echo "</pre>"; exit;
?>
```

**Output**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [div] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [label] => options
                )

            [optionchoices] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [optionIdentifier] => RESPONSE
                            [shuffle] => false
                            [maxOptions] => 1
                        )

                    [choice] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [identifier] => A1
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [identifier] => A2
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [identifier] => A3
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

In this output we get only attributes of XML.

Now what I want is to obtain Attributes as well as Values of the XML.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do with loops. first loop first xml array make array with the choice id as index and name will be the second index and then loop second output add attribute in corresponding index ..

Comment: `$xml->div->attributes()` for the first one ? Use loop following your need.

Comment: Here are several JSON formats for XML serialization, JsonML, BadgerFish, Rayfish, ... What kind of target format do you want to create?

Comment: @Abhishek have you got a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I got. And this is the solution which I expected.

http://outlandish.com/blog/xml-to-json/

Comment: Deprecated PHP8 "each" can be replaced with:            
$childTagName = key($childArray);
$childProperties = current($childArray);