# How to access attributes and values from the output xml result in php

Tags: php, xml

I am integrating a payment gateway into my website via an API provided by a third party, and I DID succeed. When it processes the payment and returns a successful result in the so-called `success.php` page, I receive the already-output xml from their `simplexml_load_string($result)`, which is printed out in the `success.php` page like this.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[error_code] => 00
[token] => 1182263526325de72aw828369e7aa
[description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[transaction_status] => 00
[receiver_email] => myemail@gmail.com
[order_code] => 3212423
[total_amount] => 200
[payment_method] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[bank_code] => NLAZ
[payment_type] => 1
[order_description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[tax_amount] => 0
[discount_amount] => 0
[fee_shipping] => 0
[return_url] => success.php
[cancel_url] => order.php
[buyer_fullname] => eric phuong
[buyer_email] => eric@domain.com
[buyer_mobile] => 012108609
[buyer_address] => abc
[affiliate_code] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[transaction_id] => 12345
)
```

What I am trying to do are:

1. Put the output result above into a variable so that I can get the values. How can I do that in a php and with .php? should I put it like this or how?:

   < ?php
   $variable = <<< XML 
   SimpleXMLElement Object 
   ( 
   [error_code] => 00
   ....
   XML;
   ?>
2. Try to get ALL the values such as the `buyer_mobile, buyer_email, etc` which are `012108609, eric@domain.com, etc`.

Can you help?

Thanks,

Eric

P/S: I also tried to read this entry `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522047/php-xml-to-array-object-with-attributes-and-values` and applied it, but no success.

Note: I already know how to parse the xml file to get the array value, but the process here in this situation is quite different that it is already output and echo'ed out in the `success.php` page. I TRY TO GET THE VALUES, but it seems to be out of my knowledge.
If the question is not clear enough to you, I can update it as per request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can get the SimpleXMLElement from the return of `simplexml_load_string($result)`

Then you can access the properties and cast them to a string because the [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) has a [__toString](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) method.

```
$variable = simplexml_load_string($result);
$buyerMobile = (string)$variable->buyer_mobile;
$buyerEmail = (string)$variable->buyer_email;
```

If you want to get the values from that response you might use a regex with an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and use `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match:

[`\[buyer_(?:email|mobile|fullname|address)\] =>\s*\K.*`](https://regex101.com/r/eHUzs4/1)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/8veXV)

Comment: it works perfectly. The point is that I have to read their returned $variable and parse it right from the `success.php` page. If I copied the output as shown above and saved it in a completely new .php page, I couldn't parse it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot @the fourth bird